# 70's sci-fi/horror film with a man causing a plane crash in London

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm in the process of tracking down a number of SF books/TV shows/films I saw or read as a child. Today I'm hunting for a science-fiction/horror film that would have been made in the early or mid-1970's.

The plot is about a man who is visiting a psychiatrist. It turns out he has psychic powers. There is a scene in which he causes an airliner to crash onto London (where the film is set). The final scene shows him bandaged and in a hospital bed. He writes the word "Windscale" (this is a nuclear reprocessing plant in the North of England) on a notepad, indicating he will destroy it.

I had thought it was *The Omega Factor* but this turns out to be a TV show, so clearly I'm misremembering.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is "[The Medusa Touch](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077921/)"

> Psychological thriller about a novelist, a telekinetic, who causes
>   disasters simply by thinking about them.

The reference to his writing 'Windscale' on a piece of paper is a dead giveaway.

Comment: Thank you! It was driving me nuts trying to recall this! When I googles it I got a link to a documentary about a radiation leak at the actual Windscale plant!